# Angular-cookies error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I try make app with include ngCookies. I'm new to use angular-cookies and when i install and include material in index. In crome console have some error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function  angular-cookies.js:25
```

I just input some material like this

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

I don't know to fix it please help me solve this problem

Comment: This is the [module.info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) documentation. It was added in [version 1.6.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - Make sure you use angularjs v1.6.3+

Comment: i try update angular to 1.6.4 with bower but still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you don't have cashing issues, try opening it from Incognito window

Comment: i open from Icognito in crome and the problem sama as with in crome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just dalete `.info({ angularVersion: '1.6.4' }).` in  angular-cookies.js line 25

Answer (score 1):

You need to update angular file and angular-cookies file to the same version. The .info fn is defined in angular.js itself. It's always been the case that the core file and the module files have to have the same version.

Comment: yeh my angular-cookies and angular it same version but still have error. version angular-cookies and angular 1.6.4

Comment: This is the version related issue mainly. There might be other dependent modules with different version. You can also refer following link https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15786 , https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10505